# A length (len) that is only 2 letters, from an item in the list

Tags: python, list

I need to find the item from the list but it only has 2 letters.

```
userlist = "fox,mi,cottage,tomatoes,bob,bo,fox"
userlist = list(userlist.split(","))
```

I'm using Python 3.8 and I'm just getting started
help me :)

Comment: You mean `list(filter(lambda item: len(item) == 2,userlist.split(",")))`?

Comment: Don't use filter, use a list comp instead

Answer (score 1):

`split()` gives you a list, so you can iterate over the elements of the list and filter the ones that have the required length:

```
templist = []
for user in userlist:
    if(len(user) == 2):
        templist.append(user)  # remember to not modify the same list while iterating over it

userlist = templist
```

Can be done in one line using list comprehension:

```
userlist = [elt for elt in userlist.split(",") if len(elt) == 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your userlist will contain elements that represents the stings you have just seperated.
In Python, you can check the length of a sting via `len(string_you_want_to_check)`. So just check that length.

```
for element in userlist:
    if len(element)==2:
        print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do:

```
  userlist = "fox,mi,cottage,tomatoes,bob,bo,fox" 
  userlist = list(userlist.split(",")) 
  for i in userlist:
      if len(i)==2:
          print i
```